# Dynamically loading HTML and CSS data from another page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to dynamically load HTML and CSS data from another page in my website project.

Suppose I have 2 pages. First one is onepage.html and second one is twopage.html. Now I have some HTML and CSS (CSS is in external sheet) data in twopage.html that I would like to feed into onepage.html.

Suppose I have a structure for twopage.html like in the snippet below:

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.col-sm-3{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p>Hello</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the data in twopage.html is dynamic, meaning that I add a set of new `div`s (in case of this example, a `.col-sm-3`) that replaces the old ones in a `row` class. This effect is something similar to appending.

I would like to load everything that is inside `row` class to onepage.html (with accompanying CSS). How could I do that? This is probably a task for JavaScript but I have no idea what is even the starting point here. What methods to use? I program my backend using Node.js and Express.js (if this comes in handy for figuring out a solution).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i got you right... You can use jQuery and load your second file (on same Server) via `$.get`

In onepage.html for example:

```
<script>

        $(function () {

            $.get("twopage.html", function (data) {
                $('.result').html($(data).find('.row').html());
            });

        });

</script>
```

and a `div.result` element in the body where to paste the filtered data:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I have partly found a solution to my problem. I used $.load method to inject HTML elements I was interested in. I then appended the CSS stylesheet in callback function. So far it works, but I am sure there are better ways to do this. The code that did the job for me:

    $("#yourId").load("myURL #container", function(){
                $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/public/css/directory.css'>"));
            });